# Model parsed with Retrofit

Tags: android, json, model, response, retrofit

I have this JSON Response that I want to parse with Model Retrofit

```
[{"category":{"id":31,"name":"App's."}},
 {"category":{"id":32,"name":"Reinvention"}}]
```

With http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ I get these models:

```
public class Category {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
}

public class CategoryResponse {
    private Category category;
}
```

And this is my Interface:

```
public interface Api {
    @GET("/categories.json")
    void getCategories(Callback <CategoryResponse> callback);
}
```

But the next call not works:

```
RestClient.get().getCategories(new Callback<CategoryResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void success(CategoryResponse categoryResponse, Response response) {

            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

            }
        });
```

Does anyone know how to parsed with Model Retrofit?

Comment: `@GET("/categories.json")
List< CategoryResponse > getCategories();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have acces to the code that generates the Json response?
Because it should be something like this:

```
{Category:[{"id":31,"name":"App's."}, 
    {"id":32,"name":"Reinvention"}]}
```

Then you just have to adjust your CategoryResponse class to use a List

```
public class CategoryResponse {
    private List<Category> category;
}
```

Even simpler would be to adjust your Json to

```
[{"id":31,"name":"App's."}, 
    {"id":32,"name":"Reinvention"}]
```

Then you only need your `Category` class and use this in your interface

```
@GET("/categories.json")
void getCategories(Callback <List<Category>> callback);
```

**EDIT**

If you can't change the Json, you should be able to parse it by using `List<CategoryResponse>` like @SorryForMyEnglish suggested.

then your interface will look like this

```
@GET("/categories.json")
void getCategories(Callback <List<CategoryResponse>> callback);
```

Comment: SnyersK, You are entirely right in this but is it possible to parse without change de JSON"?

Comment: I think that @sorryForMyEnglish 's comment should work. Because basically, your json says you have a list of objects which contain a category object. So you should be able to parse that json by using List<CategoryResponse> in you retrofit interface